# Ordered list - html : How to make point(ol{style-list:disc;}) position in midde height of image?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Ordered list - html : How to make point(ol{style-list:disc;}) position in midde height of image?

**Example where point located in bottom of image and not in middle:**

[image]

[image]

---

**The code of example**

```
<ol style="style-list:disc;">
<li><img src="https://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:MezWc3ku_XBiwM:http://www.whereisacar.com/images/cars/bill-gates-car.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="https://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:98OwBE0-icyCNM:http://www.comparecheapinsurance.com/car-insurance/images/car-insurance-policy.jpg"></li>
</ol>
```

**My parpose to move image or point position that will looks that point in middle of image height.**

**Edit:** I am looking for the way without use background point image, if this option exist

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make it ul instead of ol, like this:

```
<ul class="images">
 <li><img...
 <li><img...
</ul>
```

Then add this CSS:

```
ul.images img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the bullet in the CSS and instead use an image as a CSS property on the <li>:

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    background: url(bullet.gif) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

Also, since you're just displaying bullets, it would make more sense to use an unordered list <ul>.

Comment: Thanks, but I looking for the way without use background image

Comment: @Yosef, good luck with that, but that doesn't seem possible *without* background-images.